# Selenium: When a page is open in a new tab, is it possible to keep testing in the new page?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a menu on a page using **Selenium** and **C# webdriver**. When clicked, each of those menu items opens a page in a new Google Chrome. I wonder whether there is a way continue testing in the new chrome tab that has just been openned.

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 4):

- Yes, it is possible to test on new pages opened from current window.
- Suppose your clicking on a menu, it opens a page in new window. Your driver object will have access to current page and newly opened page in the form of window handle(or window id). We can get this window handles and switch driver control to any page using its handle.

To get current window handle to which driver has control of, we can use

```
String currentWindowHandle= driver.getWindowHandle();
```

This returns a handle to current window that uniquely identifies it within this driver instance. This can be used to switch to current window at a later stage.

To get all window handles the driver can have access to, use

```
Set<String> allWindowHandles=driver.getWindowHandles();
```

This returns a set of window handles which can be used to iterate over all open windows.

Then simply iterate the set

```
    Iterator iter = allWindowHandles.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String windowHandle=iter.next();//get window handle from set
            System.out.println(windowHandle);//this will print uique window handle id
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);// switch driver control to window having this handle id.
        // Get window title or url etc. and check whether it matches your expected page title.
//If yes, then you have navigated to correct page and then you can continue working on this page.
        if(driver.getTitle().equals("New Menu page title"))
        //then break the loop as you have got required page access.
        break;
        }
```

Comment: I think the question is tagged with C#..though anyway, good answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Get the last window handle from `WindowHandles` and switch to it:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can test in different tabs, although if you can (and want to) stick to single tab only, you can find this interesting:

http://automatictester.co.uk/2013/08/03/chromedriver-problem-with-opening-a-new-browser-tab/

I found using single tab much more straightforward in test automation - unless you really have to have multi tab testing.